# Unable to make HTTP post request to .NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, cors, rest

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC (views are running on another port using Vue). I have set up my models and controller set up and I've tested these using swagger. They work exactly as expected. I have tested the post method on swagger and it works, but requests from my view on another port running Vue and Postman return a 405 error. Inspecting the response headers on Postman, I can see "Allow : DELETE, GET, PUT". Because my view will be running on another port, I've already added CORS the following to my startup configure method (not currently concerned about security implications):

```cs
app.UseCors(builder => {
  builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod();
});
```

My controller features the following for the POST method:

```cs
[ResponseType(typeof (Review))]
[HttpPost]
public async Task Post(Review review)
{
  db.Reviews.Add(review);
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I am accessing the URL on Postman from `https://localhost:44334/reviews/Post`. Reviews being the controller and post is the method. I am not receiving any cross original control errors, just this 405. Why might it be doing this and how can I debug this?

---

I was trying to post to https://localhost:44334/reviews/Post but my router was not set up like this. Changing the URL to https://localhost:44334/reviews/ and setting the method to Post worked and returned a success 200 response.

Comment: Can you show your post request code pls? Or how do you use Postman.

Comment: What version of the .NET Core runtime are you using?

Comment: @Sergey For Postman, I select the 'POST' method and enter the URL https://localhost:44334/reviews/Post. I've added the JSON directly into the body of the request or sent empty requests. The header is kept the same, I haven't made any changes.

Comment: Did you try to remove [ResponseType(typeof (Review))] I don't know what is this for.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I'm not sure, I think it's the latest version. How can I check and how might this impact me?

Comment: @Sergey I've just just tried this and the error remains. I don't think this is related.

Comment: I tested your code but works fine , please show your route settings and how you post the values in postman

Comment: @Tisa Check the update and answer please. This has been solved.

Comment: @Mr_Happy Good, now you can mark your answer, so it can be easier for others to find the best answer.

Comment: @Tisa I'm aware, but I need to wait 12 hours first

Answer (score 0):

It is very common issue. For requests coming from localhost AllowAnyOrigin() doesn't work. You need to allow the origin explicitly like:

```cs
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("ApiCorsPolicy", builder =>
{
     builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

In the configure method tell CORS to use the policy you just created:

```cs
app.UseCors("ApiCorsPolicy");
```

Requests from postman passes the CORS because they attach special headers.

Comment: Post requests from PostMan are still getting the 405 error.

Comment: You mentioned that your frontend is written in Vue so that definitely you should use web API not MVC

Comment: I'd like to make use of some razor page views eventually for my backend. Even if I weren't, does it make a material difference to my project?